# Is there a home of New York-style pizza in NYC?

Tags: food-and-drink, new-york-city

Much like how when visiting Buffalo, and trying to get a bite of Buffalo Wings, anybody can go to any bar or restaurant to try one, but the "original" wings are at the [Anchor Bar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchor_Bar). Or, for example, if anybody wants to get a bite of the "first" hot dogs, one can go to Coney Island and go to Nathan's Famous to get a bite of one.

Where do I go in NYC to get a taste of the "original" NYC pizza?

Does it exist? Is there a birthplace for New York-style pizza that's still standing and functioning? Or is there no true birthplace for it?

Comment: I believe there's at least half a dozen places that claim to be it...

Comment: @Gagravarr Same situation in Buffalo, but the Anchor Bar has already been established as the "home" of the Buffalo Wing.

Comment: Right, as Gagr. says, it's a humorous thing known to all NY'ers that there are at least half a dozen places with big "the original!" NY Pizza signage.  The short answer is **go to a Ray's** for that original feel of horrible NY pizza.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is likely that the establishment first offering pizza in NYC is now lost in the mists of time.

Having said that, you can check out Lombardi's Pizza, 22 Spring Street (at the corner of Spring and Mott; also a one-time boundary of New York's Little Italy).  Lombardi's has been operating on the same location since 1905, and for a pizza house, that's truly amazing.   109 years!

Take the E down town and alight at Spring Street.  A if it's late.

While getting your Nathan's hot dog, you may be able to root around Coney Island and find something with similar roots.  That would be the second logical choice after what's now left of Little Italy.

The other contender, and arguably the best known, is Rays Pizza.  To my mind Ray's is the most tasty and I will invariably have one each time I'm in Manhattan.  But Ray's claim to being the 'Original' is somewhat tainted as it began in 1964, a relative infant in the Big Apple's pizza scene.

Lombardi's is your best bet, with a recommendation to have a Siciliana style at Ray's.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gennaro_Lombardi

Comment: For sure, but Lombardi's is kind of "fancy"!  For "real, crappy street food" just get a slice from a Ray's.  An don't forget to got a "papaya king" for a hotdog or the like.

Comment: LOL, don't forget that with Ray's slices you have to drain it first :)